# Batch Replace Character in File Names

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

I have about 600 video files with the **$** special character in the title.

I want to batch replace this with a letter **s**.

I found the powershell code online below and it works fine with replacing letters with other letters but fails when trying to replace the **$** special character

```
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "",""}
```

I tried using the code below and it ends up adding an s to the end of the file type instead of replacing the **$**

```
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "$","s"}
```

***$hortvid.mp4*** becomes ***$hortvid.mp4s*** instead of ***shortvid.mp4***

Any ideas on how to get this to work correctly?

Comment: For efficiency, I'f strongly advise that you incorporate a filter to ensure that you only pass the files which contain that character in the first instance. e.g. `gci -Filt *$* -File -Rec | rni …`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\` escape character:

When running line in the directory:

```
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "\$","s"}
```

input file:

```
$hortvid.mp4
```

output file is renamed:

```
shortvid.mp4
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why this works for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

$ is used for specify variable in powershell. And a string with double quote is evaluate in powershell like this :

```
$variable1="Hello"
$variable2="$variable1 world"
$variable2
```

if you dont want evaluate a character into a double quote string, you can backslash you caractere like the proposed solution of @lww. Or simply, you can use simple quote.
Like this :

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Rename-Item -Newname { $_.Name -replace '$', 's'}
```